# Как спарсить данные из <div style="data">?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `<div id="thisdiv" style="width: 30px; height: 20px"></div>`

Нужно js функцией занести в переменные два этих значения (30, 20).

Как это сделать? Под рукой есть `jquery`, но мои костыли не срабатывают. :(

Comment: elem.style.width + elem.style.height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные Вы можете получить через `css`
Пример:

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var wi = $('#thisdiv').css('width');
        var he = $('#thisdiv').css('height');
        console.log(wi);
        console.log(he);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thisdiv" style="width: 30px; height: 20px"></div>
```